# Exception in TYPO3 core update via install tool

Tags: php, typo3

When I try to upgrade TYPO3 version from installtool, I get the following exception.

> Automatic TYPO3 CMS core update not possible: Folder structure has errors or warnings
>   To perform an update, the folder structure of this TYPO3 CMS instance must stick to the conventions, or the update process could lead to unexpected results and may be hazardous to your system

Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: My guess is your folder structure is not done with symlinks. Also typo3 versions would be interessting

Answer (score 2):

If you have upgrade your typo3 version then follow this points.

1. upgrade typo3 version using instal tool. must required symlink in your typo3 installation otherwise upgrade typo3 version using instal tool not working and get following exception.
2. follow below symlink structure

   - unzip typo3_src-7.6.x.zip
   - ln -s typo3_src-7.6.x typo3_src
   - ln -s typo3_src/index.php index.php
   - ln -s typo3_src/typo3 typo3
   - ln -s typo3_src/vendor vendor
   - cp typo3_src/_.htaccess ./
3. Also installation folder structure is writable permission on your server.

Comment: It is must require to symlink TYPO3 folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you see this message you should go into the Install Tool's Folder Structure and try to solve the problems that are mentioned there. You should see a red circle with a number already next to the text "Folder structure". Like on this image:

[image: Folder structure problems]
(source: https://jweiland.net/typo3/codebeispiele/konfiguration/install-tool-warnungen-bei-folder-structure.html)